# Static string using File.ReadAllText

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-3.5

I am attempting to use `File.ReadAllText` as a static *readonly* string. My issue is I am compiling it with .NETz and when my program starts it looks for my string and if it is not 
found i get a nasty exception. Is it possible to get around this by using a if/else somehow?

Usually I would have it popup a messagebox or in label stating the file is not found.Using .Netz if the file is not found i get a error message and program does not start.

this is my static string that is used throughout my program

```
static readonly string config = File.ReadAllText("config.ini");
```

I am using .Netz to include my dll.

Comment: What's the thrown exception ?

Comment: Use a try-catch then look at the exception

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than doing it inline with the declaration, move the work to the static constructor. Then it becomes trivial to add `try/catch` blocks to handle the error cases as you see fit:

```
public class MyClass
{
    static readonly string config;

    static MyClass()
    {
        try
        {
            config = File.ReadAllText("config.ini");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            //do something else
            //use a default configuration?
            //report to the user?
            //crash and burn?
        }
    }
}
```

Note that there are [many reasons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx) why reading the file may fail besides just not being found at the path. You may want to consider catching some of those as well.

Comment: Or in case of the `FileNotFoundException`, check before if the file actually exists with `File.Exists`.

Comment: I know the file does not exist. The issue was how it was handled.

Comment: @user1908061: Checking if the file exists won't prevent it from being deleted by another thread before you can open it. See http://blog.mischel.com/2013/06/27/file-exists-is-only-a-snapshot/

Comment: @chrissinclair, I am confused about where that belongs. I have edited main question and added what I have.

Comment: @user2190928: That's fine there in your form for now. Though I'd prefer having it moved to a dedicated `Config` class of some sort rather than have it embedded within your `Form1` object.

Comment: It does not work so far so I might have to do that I suppose. I don't get any exceptions and it runs but file is not coming through. I just get nothing.

Comment: @user2190928: Have you tried debugging and making sure it's executing the code and not failing otherwise (and outputting to your console)? EDIT: Also, you don't need the `return;` call in the static constructor there.

Comment: @user2190928: That's odd. I think it _should_ have worked where it was in `Form1`. Perhaps there was a typo. At any rate, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public class configi
    {
        public static string config;
        static configi()
        {
            try
            {
                config = File.ReadAllText("config.ini");

            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    static string username = (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME"));
    static string Backups = configi.config + @"\" + username + @"\" + "Backups" + @"\";
    static string items;
```